# Passbook pass update error log

Tags: php, passbook

Im trying to figure out what this error means:

> [2013-12-01 21:11:55 -0700] Get pass task (pass type
>   pass.com.passbook, serial number 102058742, if-modified-since (null);
>   with web service url https://) encountered error: Requested serial
>   number 102058742, received serial number

when i do the manual update from the back of the pass first it shows updated then after switching the view then back to the back it shows the update time as the first time i downloaded the .pkpass instead of showing last update

It may be a logic issue with the last update date and if modified

the pass headers:

```
   $fileName = ($this->getName()) ? $this->getName() : basename($paths['pkpass']);
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header("Last-Modified:" . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
        header('Content-type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass');
        header('Content-length: '.filesize($paths['pkpass']));
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
```

here is the code that returns the pass:

```
  sendResponse(200,  $pass->create(true),'text/html' );
```

i checked the webservice via echo its returning a pass i dont know why is not updating

any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: What is the serial number of your updated pass? The serialNumber has to remain constant throughout the life cycle of a pass record.

Comment: the serial number is the same as serial displaying in error, i just did a step by step debugging. the serial number i was regenerating the pass with was NULL. I just generated a new pass with a static serial number the pass updated successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Logic issue
i was sending NULL/empty fields for the serial and name of the pass
once i fixed the null fields the pass was able to update and the error stopped logging into my error log table